# How to mirror the titlebar of an MSI installer?

Tags: user-interface, internationalization, wix, windows-installer, right-to-left

I'm trying to internationalize an installation package using WiX (Windows Installer XML), but I keep running into a problem with right to left languages (e.g. Arabic and Hebrew).

I've followed the tutorials, specifically the [right to left](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/localization/tfel-ot-thgir) tutorial. Everything appears as it should in right to left except for the titlebar of the Windows Installer dialog windows.

According to every source I've researched, including that tutorial (which is the one suggested to use by WiX on [Sourceforge](http://wix.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html)), mirroring the titlebar is currently impossible.

Has anyone successfully mirrored the titlebar of the Windows Installer dialog windows? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: The title bar is drawn by the window manager so you'd get a mirrored one when you have an RTL UI language. That's the case for pretty much every program, though.

Comment: The title bar is handled automatically by Windows. So on Arabic machines it should be right to left by default. Did you test your package on an Arabic machine?

Comment: Although I cannot completely agree with what Joey or Cosmin say (you can actually revert title bar of any Portable Executable by placing two strong directionality marks (RLE) next to its Version Info) but in case of MSI files, this would be handled via Windows Installer (MSI itself) and it would look different depending on the Operating System. I don't think you can control it from WiX source code.

Comment: I ran the right-to-left (RTL) installer on a dev machine with a brand new installation of Windows 7 Ultimate installed in Arabic. Everything in the UI appeared RTL except for the title bar: the icon, window title, and minimize-maximize-close buttons. They were all LTR as though they were on a LTR machine. I have screenshots, does anyone know how to upload them here? Also, what are those directionality marks you mentioned? Can I try them with msi?

Comment: Accoding to [this](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-199286.html), it might be a limitation of Windows Installer...